# MacBook Pro 7,1 OS X upgrade to Lion or Mavericks

Tags: snow-leopard, upgrade

I own a MacBook Pro 7,1 running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and need to upgrade my operating system in order to allow my kids access Netflix as it says I need to update my browser.

Apple software update says I have latest available software.

Can I download Lion or Mavericks from anywhere?

As I don't really want to risk going to Yosemite in case it renders my MacBook Pro useless.

Comment: Is there a particular fear you have about Yosemite rendering your macbook "useless" as opposed to any other OS upgrade?

Comment: The MacBook Pro 7,1 will run Yosemite without causing it to become useless. This model was released with 4GB of RAM, which is adequate. There is also an EFI firmware update that should be applied.

Answer (score 1):

OS X Yosemite runs amazingly on my 2009 MacBook Pro (5,3). I don't know who started all this nonsense about Yosemite running poorly on all Macs, but it's perfectly safe and very useful on new Macs and even ones like mine that are a few years old.

Answer (score 0):

To get a legal version of Lion you have to buy it [here](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion) (us) or [there](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/D6106ZM/A/os-x-lion) (uk). If you live in another country replace the uk in the uk-link by the appropriate country code.